# Java and python processes can exclusive lock the same file on linux

Tags: java, python, linux

I have a java app and a python launcher for it. The java app locks a file to avoid multiple startups using this code:

```
java.nio.channels.FileLock lock = lockWrapper.getChannel().tryLock();
if (lock == null) {
     logger.info("Anotheris already running");
}
lock.release();
staticLock = lockWrapper.getChannel().lock();
```

The python launcher tries to lock on the same file with fcntl and it can. Two java processes can't do this and neither two python processes can lock exclusively on the same file. But a java and a python can, in any directions.
I'm on a xubuntu with openjdk 6 and python2.7 I use portalocker for python.

```
    lockfile =open(lockfilename, 'w+')
    portalocker.lock(lockfile, portalocker.LOCK_EX| portalocker.LOCK_NB)
```

Also work fine on win7.

Comment: Can you not look for another process of the same name running?

Comment: You could use `strace` to understand which syscalls are involved.

Comment: Could you update your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of your java and python code. I think I have a solution for you.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh: The java example is there. And the python one does not hold too much info, but I post it for you (FYI, lockWrapper is a RandomAccessFile in the java code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer from a co-worker and it's quite simple. Java does not use the POSIX locks, but python does. So they can't inter operate...

---

Actually they could, but only if one can force both runtimes to use the same locking mechanisms. But that forces you to hardcode it making the code fragile and very platform dependent.

Comment: Maybe you could use atomic file creation (in java [File.createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) idk if something like that is available in python) and a dummy lock file. If it can't be created, because it is already there, deny startup. But that introduces other problems (rogue lock file after unclean shutdowns) and is of course not applicable if you need a lock on the file for other reasons (as stated in the javadoc).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Linux el6.
Oracle Java 7 using FileLock and python 2.6 can properly lock a file.
Edit: Use F_SETLKW for blocking/waiting operation.

Python code not portable.  That's not an issue in my environment.

```
import fcntl, struct, time

f = open("/tmp/TestLock","w")

lockdata = struct.pack('hhllhh', fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
unlockdata = struct.pack('hhllhh', fcntl.F_UNLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
while True:
    try:
        fcntl.fcntl(f.fileno(),fcntl.F_SETLK, lockdata)
        print "Lock held"
        time.sleep(5)
    except IOError as ex:
        print "Lock failed: "+ex.strerror
        if ex.errno == 11:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            break
        continue
    else:
        fcntl.fcntl(f.fileno(),fcntl.F_SETLK, unlockdata)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html
Search page for SVR4 (at the bottom)

Reference: https://community.dur.ac.uk/physics.astrolab/file_locking.html

Comment: If you don't feel like all that coding, on Linux systems lockf does what you want: